# How to take a 300 DPI screenshot of a web page

Tags: printing, dpi

Ok, dumb question, the images on the page are all 72, so you can't have 300.  But... what's the best way to print in as high resolution as possible on a brochure?

Comment: It's not dumb. I look forward to hearing the responses to this.

Comment: Make everything 4 times bigger than it needs to be, then screenshot in 72dpi? (Make sure the enlarged images are actually high-res, and not badly scaled.)

Comment: Why are there 2 votes to close?

Comment: Why is this a programming-related question? Shouldn't it be on super-user?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can get a high resolution print from a generic web page keeping the layout perfectly right (so, if your objective is to illustrate how it looks on screen but with print quality, this should be a showstopper).

Even if the text and many elements are a kind of vectorial (scalable) graphic (i.e. in theory you could zoom the page so they are rendered bigger and enlarge the browser window to get an enlarged screenshot), many graphic elements ("normal" images) are raster graphic, that cannot be enlarged without ugly artifacts coming out.

Moreover, many layouts use pixels for sizes of various elements (which means that scaling things up and down may make the layout become a mess).

Comment: On the other hand, rounded corners and many other elements can scale.

Answer (score 2):

How about zooming in on the web-page before taking the screen-shot? Most modern browsers allow you to set a custom zoom level.

Note though that the images may not look as great as you would like. You can't do much about this without access to high-res version of the images.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser re-renders for print, and a CSS compliant one should (to respect print display specific rules), then it should be rendering to the resolution of the output device.
If you can then output to raw postscript or a high res PDF, perhaps you'd be able to get these high quality printable parts via that route.

Answer (score -1):

Print to PDF. You can't increase the resolution of the images period without shrinking them. The text will be vectors and therefore will scale to any resolution.

Comment: However, not images. PDF image resizing is a nightmare and looks terrible.

Answer (score -3):

I think the best way is to use Photoshop or any other imaging software which supports different resolutions. After grabbing the screenshot, create a new file in your imaging software then change the resolution to 300. Last step is to paste the image from clipboard.

This way won't increase the actual resolution of the image on print but the quality of print is actually higher. I checked this way and it works for me.

Comment: This works fine if it's ok for you to print in (relatively) small format. For example, a 1680x1050 screenshot will result in a 5.6"x3.5" (14.2x8.9 cm) print with not-so-readable body text (if it's written in "usual" sizes).

Comment: Usually we don't want to make a poster out of a screenshot so this may not be a serious problem.